# Borland string::find bug

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, c++builder-5

I'm supporting a C++ application written using Borland C++ Builder 5.02 (from 1997). The find() method on the Borland string class does not behave how I would expect:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   string needle = "length == eighteen";
   string haystack = "<" + needle + ">";
   if (haystack.find(needle) != NPOS)
      cout << "Found it!" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Not found" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `Not found`. If I change the needle to something shorter it outputs `Found it!`. If I exchange the angle brackets for some other characters it finds it. Spaces work, but parentheses also don't.

Note that I am using the Borland string library here: if I `#include <string>` and use `std::string` instead then it works exactly how I would expect. Sadly changing the whole application to use STL strings is not a feasible answer!

From the documentation it seems that Borland uses a hash-based algorithm for string search. I can't find any more details about this, and I've stepped through the disassembly but am not much the wiser.

I find it very hard to believe that this is really a bug in the string library, particularly since if it were then I would expect to be able to find an article or something about it. I can't find any such information.

However, I've run out of ideas! Is this a known bug? Is there a fix?

EDIT: Having looked again at the disassembly, I think it's trying to do something like the Rabin-Karp algorithm, where the hash function is calculated mod 33554393 (the largest prime < 2^25). It could well be the polynomial hash function with a base of 32 (i.e. a_0 + 32 a_1 + 32^2 a_2 + .. + 32^n a_n) but that's just a hunch. Sounds like a possible overflow as Daniel Fischer suggested.

Comment: "hash-based algorithm", "If I change the needle to something shorter" <- that smells of integer overflow.

Comment: This is what happens when you rely on 15 year old compilers. Time to move on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It can be difficult to move on when there's no budget.

Comment: @PeterWood It can be difficult to stay put when there's no budget

Comment: When you find the bug, what are you going to do? Submit a bug report to Borland and ask them to fix it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This question has arisen as part of a project to migrate this (completely working and very profitable) system over to a more modern compiler. 'Moving on' is what we're doing. But it has to keep on working exactly as it currently does, and http://pragmatictips.com/26 tells me to suspect my own errors over library bugs as the former are astonishingly more likely. Hence the question.

Comment: Your are right to suspect your own errors. But the code is pretty clear. It's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you though. Who else is going to be using this compiler? I suspect you'll need to debug it yourself. Do you have the source for the runtime library?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't care about fixing the library. If it's a known library bug then we can justify changing the application to work around it (e.g. using `strstr()`) and migrate the altered code.  What amazed me was that I couldn't find any evidence that this was a known library bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I still have BCB5 installed, so I will test the provided code and see if it is actually an STL bug or not. But I suspect it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a reference from 1998 suggesting Borland's implementation of searching strings has a bug:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/borland.public.cpp.language/cstring$20bug/borland.public.cpp.language/XBzjaJmCYpk/gtMPm-j8jugJ

Also, it appears that at some point in history the C++ commitee decided that a string class would be part of standard C++, and cstring's string class is a remnant of this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/borland.public.cpp.language/borland$20cstring/borland.public.cpp.language/2psY2seRmS4/ywVrqwU1C2wJ

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original BC++ 5.02 installation disk, the string class source is found under BC5\SOURCE\RTL\SOURCE\STRING.

Here is an excerpt from the code of the string::find_case_index() function (called by string::find() ):

```
const long q = 33554393L;
const long q32 = q<<5;

size_t testlength = length() - startindex;
size_t patternlength = patl = strlen(cp);
if( testlength < patternlength )
    return NPOS;
if( patternlength == 0 )
    return 0;

long patternHash = 0;
long testHash = 0;

const char _FAR *testP = c_str()+startindex;
const char _FAR *patP = cp;
long x = 1;
size_t i = patternlength-1;

while( i-- )
    x = (x<<5)%q;

for( i=0; i<patternlength; i++ )
    {
    patternHash = ( (patternHash<<5) + *patP++  ) % q;
    testHash    = ( (testHash   <<5) + *testP++ ) % q;
    }

testP = c_str()+startindex;
const char _FAR *end = testP + testlength - patternlength;

while (1)
    {

    if(testHash == patternHash)
        if( !get_paranoid_check_flag() ||
            !strncmp( testP, cp, patternlength) )
          return (size_t)(testP-c_str());

    if( testP >= end )
        break;

    // Advance & calculate the new hash value:
    testHash = ( testHash + q32 - *testP * x                 ) % q;
    testHash = ( (testHash<<5)  + *(patternlength + testP++) ) % q;
    }
return NPOS;          // Not found.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. I'm sure there's an installation CD knocking around somewhere; I never even thought of looking on it for source.

Comment: If you find the CD and decide to try to apply a fix to the source, look here for instructions how to build the RTL, along with a fix to another bug: http://www.jogy.net/bcrtlfix.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a Borland string library.  `String` (capital S) is the Borland string class. `string` (lowercase s), which is the exact same thing as `std::string`, is the STL string class, which is NOT a Borland implementation (the STL in BCB5 was the RogueWave STL).  Your use of `#include <cstring>` is likely bringing `std::string` into the global namespace, which is why your code compiles.  But you really should be using `#include <string>` and `std::string` instead.  As for `NPOS`, you should be using `string::npos` instead, since that is what `string::find()` actually returns.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   string needle = "length == eighteen";
   string haystack = "<" + needle + ">";
   if (haystack.find(needle) != string::npos)
      cout << "Found it!" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Not found" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::string needle = "length == eighteen";
   std::string haystack = "<" + needle + ">";
   if (haystack.find(needle) != std::string::npos)
      std::cout << "Found it!" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same version of the class library. I can't find a `String` class in my system and the `string` I'm using is definitely not `std::string` - e.g. it has a `contains()` method whereas my `std::string` does not. The class library docs are definitely about a `string` class. Neither of your programs compile for me: the first says `undefined symbol 'npos'` and your second says `'cout' is not a member of 'std'`. [... TBC]

Comment: [contd ...] You say you have BCB5 installed - is this 5.02 or the freely available 5.5? Can you compile and run the program I gave and, if so, do you see the same output? That would be most helpful.

Comment: @DaveTurner: I don't think we are even talking about the same **product**. You said you are using **Borland C++ Builder** (which is what I have installed), but I think you are actually using **Borland C++** instead.  They are **NOT** the same product. In **Borland C++**, cstring.h defined a non-standard `string` class that is not the STL `std::string` class.

Comment: @DaveTurner: **Borland C++ Builder** uses the STL `std::string` class, and its VCL framework also defines a separate `System::String` class that is binary-compatible with Delphi.